# Changing Values in a Matrix based on a condition

Tags: r, matrix, apply

So I have seen many posts about altering all values in a matrix less than a certain number equal to zero with some simple indexing of the matrix. But I think what I have is a little more advanced and I am having some trouble so hopefully you guys can help out. Here is the code I am working with:

```
x <- (1:5)
y <- c(0,10,0,0,8)
n <- 12 

mat <- t(sapply(y, function(test) pmax(seq(test, (test-n+1), -1), 0) ))
mat
```

This produces:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[2,]   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2     1     0     0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[5,]    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0     0     0     0

xmat <- replicate(ncol(mat),x)
```

Then I wanted to find which y does not equal to zero and then replace the values in xmat to zero until mat equals zero and then change the value to the x value. So below is what I currently have.

```
CountTest <- which(y != 0)

xmat[CountTest,] <- apply(xmat[CountTest,], 1, function(xu) ifelse(xu > 0, 0, xu))
xmat
```

This produces:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3     3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
```

The desired output is:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     2     2
[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3     3     3
[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    5     5     5     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
> xmat*(mat==0)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     2     2
#[3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3     3     3     3
#[4,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4     4
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    5     5     5     5
```

Comment: So I have been working in R for a little bit, but I am never sure when to coerce something into binary like you just did. Do you have any suggestions or should I post that as a whole separate question?

Comment: A logical value `TRUE` or `FALSE` is converted into a numerical `1` or `0`, respectively, whenever it is combined with an arithmetic operation, like an addition or multiplication. 
As an example, `(5 > 2) + 0` will yield `1`, just as the result of `(2==2) * 1` is `1`. I don't know if these examples answer your question. If you feel that you need more clarifications maybe you can post a separate question.

Comment: basically what you are saying is that in this case coercing into binary would be seen as useful because we are essentially making it into a TRUE or FALSE statement. So your answer reflects that logic.

Comment: We probably mean the same, but I think I'd put it somewhat differently. The comparison `mat==0` yields a matrix with logical entries `TRUE`and `FALSE`. Since `xmat` is numeric, the multiplication makes only sense if the multiplier is numeric, too. This is recognized by `R`, and hence the logical values are coerced into numeric ones. There are certainly more formal ways of describing the coercion, which is connected with the different flexibility of the various types of variables, but this simple description might be sufficient to explain most cases.

Comment: The section "Coercion" in [the recent book by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html) provides more accurate information on this topic.